# Change date "July 29th, 2011" to "20110729"

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have lots of HTML files contains date with format `July 29th, 2011`

I want to change date format `July 29th, 2011` to `20110729`, `December 9th, 2010` to `20101209`, etc.

I think `sed` may works but still can't find the solution because of its indirect sequence.

Comment: You'd be better off with perl which can read one date format and output another, but my perl-foo isn't good enough, hopefully someone else will chip in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sort of thing is much more difficult than it should be with most tools.  GNU `awk` and Perl's POSIX module both give you a `strftime()`, but not a `strptime()`, which is what you want.

In any case, it is still pretty easy with Perl...

```
$ perl -MDate::Manip -lpe '$_=UnixDate(ParseDate($_), "%Y%m%d")' <<END
> July 29th, 2011
> December 9th, 2010
> END
20110729
20101209
```

Obviously there's more to it, since you actually want to convert the HTML.  If you can figure out a regex with sed that will work to *find* the date strings, you should be able to do something very similar with Perl.

```
$ perl -MDate::Manip -lpe 's/(")([^"]+)(")/$1 . UnixDate(ParseDate($2), "%Y%m%d") . $3/ge' <<END
dates enclosed "July 29th, 2011" in quotes
"December 9th, 2010"
END
dates enclosed "20110729" in quotes
"20101209"
```

Comment: Where/How do I get the `Date::Manip` module? ... My perl gives me an error, *"Can't locate Date/Manip.pm in @INC ..."*. Is it an *extra* module I need to install somehow? ... I'm using perl, v5.10.1

Comment: @fred: Most distro package managers will have this, try searching there. On my system the package name is `perl-Date-Manip` but yours will vary. You could also get it using `cpan`.

Comment: @StevenPritchard: You write good and useful answers, I'm glad to see you around this community. I would just like to note that **this community depends on votes** in order to keep functioning. Not only do votes help sort answers but they shape the site by changing what is visible where, search results, and most importantly help keep good users around to police the site. Without votes it dies. You have only cast 3 votes total. You are given 30 to use each day! _Please consider using your knowledge to improve this site by voting on on what you think is valuable or not._

Comment: *@Caleb:* Thanks. It's in Ubuntu's repository as `libdate-manip-perl` .... *@Steven Pritchard:* It is a nice solution... Thanks.

Comment: @Caleb: You'll note that the majority of my answers, and those 3 votes, were all this week.  I'm still getting used to the site.  :-)

Comment: @StevenPritchard: Yes I noticed, hence the explanation drawing your attention to a key feature. It certainly does take a little getting used to. Even once you understand all the buttons, each SE site has a little bit of it's own culture and etiquette. See you around!

Comment: Here is a small note about `strftime()` and `strptime()`, which wasn't immediately clear to me: From `man strptime`; 
*"The strptime() function is the converse function to strftime()"*

Comment: GNU date does have both parsing and printing, but `July 29th, 2011` isn't a recognized format (`July 29, 2011` works), and you'd need to put quite a bit of shell and sed/awk infrastructure around it.